# Click image import

Tags: jquery

```
<div class="leftThumbNail">   
    <img id = "img1" src="img/thumb/image1.jpg" class = "image1Position" alt="Image 1">
    <img id = "img2" src="img/thumb/image2.jpg" class = "image2Position" alt="Image 2" >
</div>
```

The above represent a class which has two images stored within it. It is laid out such that whenever I click on the ether one of the two images, it reacts.

```
$(".leftThumbNail").on("click", function(){ 
    var img = $(this).find("img"), // select images inside thumbnail,but which one?
    alert(this.id); //prints empty for some reason, I want to have it print the one I clicked on within the class such that I can import a specific image after it is clicked.
});
```

How can one identify which image within the class that I've clicked? Say I click on `img1` and I would like to import another image,how would one do that?

Comment: Why don’t you just put the event on the images, so you will know directly which one was clicked …?

Comment: your event handler is attached to the `div` so that's what `this` points to. just attach the handler to the `img` elements using `$(".leftThumbNail img").on( ... );`

Comment: how would one than import an image if say I clicked on `img1`?

Comment: I tried to use your suggest, but it brings back the problem of draggable images and allowing right click. Also what I meant by import is that I am to change a picture at another destination rather than the current clicked image. But the idea is that each picture has its own pair. So when I click `img1`, `bigImg1` will show location x where x is not where `img1` is located. When I click `img2`, `bigImg2` will replace the image at location x.

Comment: Is `bigImg1` a ID? if so you can use `$('#bigImg1 ').attr('src',this.src);`

Comment: yes `bigImg1` is a ID that is within the class `bigImage`. Does the class wrapper around `bigImg1` affect it?

Comment: If it is a ID you can use the code I wrote above (just the source I am not sure what you want to use). What is the css of that class? it makes no difference for the code, just for the display.

Comment: I got it thanks so much. One last question, can one import images but hide them in html?

Comment: Sure, .hide() should do the trick. Maybe `$('#bigImg1 ').attr('src',this.src).hide();`. Or using that class you have around.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a click listener targeted to the `<div class="leftThumbNail>`, which means `this.id` is empty. Use `event.target` instead of `this`.

Try this:

```
$(".leftThumbNail").on("click", function(event){ 
    var img = event.target, // select images inside thumbnail
    alert(img.id); 
});
```

Read more about `event.target` on [**MDN**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/event.target)

**Or** you could use instead `$(".leftThumbNail img").on("click", function(){`, then you could use just `alert(this.id);` because `this` would be the `img` element.

---

To change the image you could the use:

```
var new_image_url = 'new.jpg';
this.src = new_image_url; // or event.target.src, depending on the 2 options above
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using the element that was passed (`e.target.id`) this way:

```
$(".leftThumbNail").on("click", function(e){ 
    console.log(e.target.id); 
});
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/PP9Fm/2)**